# Effect of a ground in a circuit

Tags: ground, diagram

From the picture, the switch can be considered 'closed'. Could someone explain what effect the 'ground' has on the different currents (I1, I2...)? If I had the exact same diagram, except WITHOUT the ground, what would be different? What about when the switch is opened after a long time?

[image: circuit diagram]

Comment: One effect of that ground connection is to make me want to smack whoever drew that circuit.  Ground pointing UP?  Really?

Comment: (Bud, you need to put at least the ground at the bottom... :-)

Comment: You misunderstand what a "ground" means. A Ground is just a point of reference where we define that the voltage is 0 V (zero Volt). In this circuit the ground connection **cannot** influence the circuit as there is only **one** ground connection. You should know that currents travel in loops. There can be no loop with only one ground connection.

Comment: Although I agree this circuit is not drawn in a sensible way and neither is the location of the ground connection, it does not change the behavior of the circuit in any way. This is clearly an excersise for applying Kirchhoff's laws, not a sensible or useful circuit.

Comment: Thanks all - I'm actually a tutor, and one of my students came across this question, and I'm not overly familiar with grounds in circuit diagrams (I know, I need to get familiar!) - it just wasn't common in his questions.

Forgive my lack of understanding, but wouldn't the current from the battery (24V potential), be drawn directly to the ground? If not, why not?

Comment: If ground is always at the bottom, then we become predisposed to putting it there, and don't consider any other option that may, in fact, lead to a simpler analysis.

Comment: @JRE, with a negative power supply like we have here, I'd rather have the ground at the top.

Comment: @JRE, Maybe the designer was Australian. I have the same issues with folks that have the inputs on the right and the outputs on the left......

Comment: @Trevor: Those drive me nuts, too.

Answer (score 1):

If the ground was removed and replaced with its own voltage node, and analyzed the voltages relative to each other they would not be different from the circuit with ground, however you would not know how the value of the nodes relative to anything outside the circuit.

You could move ground to any point in the circuit and the relative voltages would be the same, but only because the ground node has no current flowing through it to another point in the circuit.

Comment: Thank you - I think I understand now; the ground indicates that any point directly connected to the ground (without passing any R's or C's) is at a potential of 0V.

I suppose that means that the voltage on the 'other side' of the circuit elements is negative? And the battery would have terminal voltages of 0(+) and -24(-)?

Comment: Actually that's not strictly speaking quite true. If the wiring and components have capacitance to the ground then it will affect things very, very, slightly. But for this example... not really worth the effort it took to type this...

Comment: In the real world, no. In the ideal world yes. I don't even want to get into real world grounding. The craziest thing is when you have spacecraft charging because its floating in plasma, and it does affect the circuits. So that would be like putting a voltage source in between ground and your circuit. Things can get crazy

Answer (score 0):

This image is from a circuit analysis exercise problem. The ground symbol has no effect on the currents and voltages in the circuit. One can well take an eraser and wipe it off. If the writer of the problem asked some node voltages, the ground symbol would show the reference node and that makes it important in exercices.

In real schematics of electronic equipment the ground symbol states that this is the wire that needs no shielding against the disturbing fields.  The shieldings would be connected to this. Different parts of the circuit can have their own grounds that have one connection between each other.

In schematics the ground symbol is widely used also to make the drawing easier to read. Much long lines can be replaced by a well known symbol.

In electric power systems the grounding is physical - a wire inside the soil, It is extremely important for the safety. Electric equipment often have a metal case. It should be connected to real earth for safety until double insulation is applied.